# NSNetServiceBrowser: why does bonjour not see the computer on windows 7 on a LAN?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, bonjour

I did the class detection device names through bonjour (with NSNetServiceBrowser). Trying to find devices in the LAN via smb:

```
[self.bonjourBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_smb._tcp" inDomain:nil];
```

In the method of delegate found only two devices:

- D-Link DNS-315
- AirPort Time Capsule

But bonjour does not see the third device (computer on windows 7). Although the Finder sees it and I can connect to it via smb: //192.168.1.5

How to detect the computer on windows 7 in LAN through Bonjour? May be specify the other **type** when searching (and not "_smb._tcp") or another **domain**?

Comment: Have you installed bonjour services for Windows on that computer?

Comment: No, i have not. But how the Finder detected this computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finder doesn't use Bonjour - it uses SMB directly.  When you are looking for _"smb._tcp" you are looking for SMB services advertised using Bonjour, just as "_ipp._tcp" would be Internet Print Protocol on TCP advertised by Bonjour.

[Bonjour services for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999) is a free download from Apple and without it installed you will not discover Windows computers using Bonjour.

Answer (score 0):

You need fix your service type to @"_smb._tcp.". Note that the period character at the end is required.

Answer (score 0):

DNS-SD (aka. Bonjour or mDNS) has been on Apple platforms long time ago.

Windows 10 servers support mDNS, but older Windows servers(in your case windows7) must install Bonjour software(Paulw11 metioned it) which is not the case for most users.

That's why you cannot see your windows7 on the discovered result.